# Bus.Reply when called from Saga and non-Saga

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus4

I have an NServiceBus endpoint that handles saving documents to a document management system.  After the document is saved, I call `Bus.Reply(new DocumentSaved{})`.

This works fine when I am sending `SaveDocument` from a Saga (which cares deeply about the reply), but it fails when I am sending it from my web client endpoint (i.e. an MVC project, which doesn't care at all about the reply).  The failure is because my web client endpoint doesn't have a queue to process the reply.

What am I doing wrong here?  (I really don't want to have to create a queue for my MVC project to hold a bunch of replies that will never ever get processed.)

Comment: Is the MVC endpoint a SendOnly endpoint?

Comment: I had no idea such a configuration option existed!  Please make an answer out of this and I will surely mark as accepted, pending giving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Replies are just normal messages. The only thing that links original messages and relies is correlation id, which is stored in the message header and the originator address, where a reply is sent to.

This means that all rules that apply to normal messages are also applicable to replies. There are no special "reply queues". Replies go to normal queues as any other message.

I suspect that you have no message-endpoint mapping configuration in your web endpoint. I am not sure if SendOnly endpoint has any effect here, since I assume you already received a message there, which you want to send a reply to.

I would start by checking the message assembly to endpoint mapping and enabling debug level logging.